# Getting item level security on SharePoint online through standard web services

Tags: web-services, security, sharepoint-online

SharePoint 2010 and 2007 have a known limitation where you can't access item level security metadata (for example permissions assigned at folders and list items) using the standard web services (sitedata.asmx, permissions.asmx, lists.asmx, etc). To overcome this, you have to install/deploy a custom web service which does that for you in the server side and then sends back the security information.

I'm trying to do the same in SharePoint Online (or SharePoint for Office 365) which is a version of SharePoint 2010 which runs in the cloud (either hosted by Microsoft of by your company).

The main change here is how authentication works, but besides that, you cannot install a custom web service into SharePoint online. So, the previous approach doesn't work.

Does anyone know of any alternatives to fetch this information?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is that limitation documented? DVWPs and jQuery access to lists.asmx returns only the items a user has access to.

Comment: Ok. The limitation is not getting access to items a user has access to, but getting security metadata of items (for any user) using the standard web services. Sitedata.asmx and permissions.asmx return security information, but only at site and list level.

Comment: This is referenced [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/63861/Limitations-of-SharePoint-Web-Services#6), and I have checked that myself.